# Handling data from external Bluetooth device with GPS NMEA strings

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps, external, android-bluetooth

We have external Bluetooth device, that delivers different type of data to android device. Among others it delivers also GPS NMEA string.
GPS NMEA data should be used to update android system GPS module. And other data will be parsed in our application.

How is this possible to achieve?

ATM: I parse all data from external device, but android GPS module does not receive NMEA strings. GPS must be handled by android system GPS module to update navigation software. This software uses just android GPS data, it does not support functions to pump in data from other applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** I used mock locations. At the moment it is not possible to avoid GPS NMEA string parsing.

**Code:**

```
String mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.addTestProvider(mocLocationProvider, false, false, false, false, true, true, false, Criteria.POWER_LOW, Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true);
mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus(mocLocationProvider, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE, null, System.currentTimeMillis());

//update location
Location mCurrentLocation = new Location(mocLocationProvider);
                           mCurrentLocation.setLatitude(mGPSCurrLat);
                           mCurrentLocation.setLongitude(mGPSCurrLon);
                           mCurrentLocation.setAccuracy(1);
                           mCurrentLocation.setTime(mGPSCurrTimeUTC); //long getTime() from UTC string
                           mCurrentLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());

mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(mocLocationProvider, mCurrentLocation);
```

**Note:**
Enable "Allow mock locations" in android settings!

Answer (score 0):

CM version <= 10 support GPS source selection, from there you can select paired devices and use them as a source for GPS.

---

There is an xposed module that works on android >= 4.2
https://plus.google.com/communities/104930572010612794860

---

if you don't have problem with not having satellites info, you can also use Bluetooth Gps from PlayStore (require mock locations)
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=googoo.android.btgps&hl=it

Comment: I was looking for developers solution